# Is there a way to two files in one command in the same directory path?

Tags: unix, zsh

Let's say I'm doing something like this:

```
touch app/api/api.rb && touch app/api/user/data.rb
```

is there any way I can make this shorter, so that I don't have to repeat the `touch app/api/` part?  I tried `touch app/api/api.rb{/user/data.rb}` but it doesn't work.

Comment: `(cd app/api ; touch api.rb data.rb)`

Comment: @MarcB Do not forget to return to current folder...

Comment: Thanks, but they aren't in the same directory.  `api.rb` is in `app/api/` and `data.rb` is in `app/api/user/` and I don't want to change directories because then I'll just have to write another line afterwards to change directories back, which actually adds another step to the process rather than shortening the one-step process.

Comment: @Crowley: `()` creates a subshell, so any dir changes in the subshell are lost when control returns to the parent.

Comment: @katgus: then `touch api.rb user/data.rb`. the cd will be "undone" when the subshell created by `()` exits, and you'll be right back to where you started at. otherwise, yes, you'll have to specify the full path for both files, since you're dealing with a "foreign directory". there's no way around this. either cd to where you want to work, or you have to include the full path of that work location each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`zsh` supports [brace expansion](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Brace-Expansion).

```
touch app/api/{api,user/data}.rb
```

Comment: Thank you!  This is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Use a subshell:

```
marc@panic:~$ (cd foo ; pwd); pwd
                         ^-#1  ^-#2
/home/marc/foo  <-#1
/home/marc      <-#2
```

The subshell 'cd' will be lost/undone when the subshell exits, and the parent/controlling shell will be right wherever it was.